Parallelization of TCP Stack in embedded Linux
I have a ARM Cortex-A9 dual-core processor running with 800MHz. An yocto based embedded Linux with kernel 5.15 (will be updated to 6.6 soon) is executed on the ARM processor.
When I transfer data through TCP with iperf3 -c <IP> --zerocopy the maximum bitrate is 760Mbits/s. A single core is fully used (100%) for some kernel space functions within the iperf3 tool. I assume, that the TCP package generation needs this time.
Is there any kernel configuration to enable multi-threading and allowing to use both cores for the TCP Stack?
